# C: take screenshot

Tags: c, windows, screenshot

How can I capture screen and save it as am image in C?
OS: windows (XP & Seven)

Thanks

Comment: That's a bit vague and depends hugely on the underlying OS. In any case, you'd have to go through the API that comes with your OS, fetch raw pixel data, and save it as an image - for that last part, you probably want to use an existing library so you won't be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Please consider adding information to this question. Operating system? Graphics environment? Available libraries?

Comment: You are probably looking to use some combination of `BitBlt`, `GetDC` and `GetDesktopWindow`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to take screenshots of a Window with C++ in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531684/what-is-the-best-way-to-take-screenshots-of-a-window-with-c-in-windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [google](http://www.google.com)? This [forum entry](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/post593378.html#post593378) has an example, complete with C source code using the Win32 API.

EDIT: Found a duplicate in the meantime: [How can I take a screenshot and save it as JPEG on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997175/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-and-save-it-as-jpeg-on-windows)

Answer (score 4):

in case you don't want to bother to click on link

```
#include <windows.h>

bool SaveBMPFile(char *filename, HBITMAP bitmap, HDC bitmapDC, int width, int height);

bool ScreenCapture(int x, int y, int width, int height, char *filename){
  // get a DC compat. w/ the screen
  HDC hDc = CreateCompatibleDC(0);

  // make a bmp in memory to store the capture in
  HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(GetDC(0), width, height);

  // join em up
  SelectObject(hDc, hBmp);

  // copy from the screen to my bitmap
  BitBlt(hDc, 0, 0, width, height, GetDC(0), x, y, SRCCOPY);

  // save my bitmap
  bool ret = SaveBMPFile(filename, hBmp, hDc, width, height);

  // free the bitmap memory
  DeleteObject(hBmp);

  return ret;
}

main(){
  ScreenCapture(500, 200, 300, 300, "testScreenCap.bmp");
  system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Hi, This doesn't work for me too! I thought we don't have "bool" datatype in C (?) . it rises this error : "expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'SaveBMPFile'" & the same error for "ScreenCapture" function

Comment: Try the following: typedef char bool; #define true 1 #define false 0

Comment: OK, for followers I took the liberty of putting together a compilable file (including the absent SaveBMPFile method) here: https://gist.github.com/rdp/9821698 (@4r1y4n you need to compile using g++)

Comment: This question was not tagged "c++".