# SaveBMPFile undefined reference

Tags: c, winapi, screenshot

I got the code snippet from here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370702/c-take-screenshot)

The error is: Undefined reference to `SaveBMPFile`
Thanks in advance.

Comment: here's my gist of it with working code: https://gist.github.com/rdp/9821698

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the code you are using was originally copied from [this forum thread](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/119804/screenshot-maybe-win32api#post593378). Notice that it says "The SaveBMPFile function referenced above is attached (I didn't write it)" and provides [an attachment](http://static.daniweb.com/images/attachments/0/saveBMP.cpp) that contains the definition.