# change background image in body

Tags: javascript, css

How do i change the background image in CSS  at run time? I have the following background image in body and can the image be changed at run time?

```
body {
height: 100%;
background: #fff8db url(../images/backgrounds/header-top.jpg) no-repeat center top; 
/*background-color: #fff8db;*/
/*background-size: 1650px 900px;*/
font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size:12px; 
font-weight:normal; 
color:#404040;
line-height:20px; }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have JQuery loaded already, you can just do this:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(../images/backgrounds/header-top.jpg)');
```

**EDIT**:

First load JQuery in the head tag:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then call the Javascript to change the background image when something happens on the page, like when it finishes loading:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(../images/backgrounds/header-top.jpg)');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried apply your code in the html, but no changes. <script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(../images/backgrounds/header-top1.jpg)');
</script>

Comment: Just to point out, the original question asks for a strictly javascript answer and this utilizes jquery. The answer below is the correct way to do this according to the actual question. Not sure why this got picked as best answer.

Comment: The answer starts with "If you have JQuery loaded already...", which a lot of websites already do.

Comment: For pure javascript code, you have to use the `background` syntax, and not the `backgroungImage`. e.q. `element.style.background = "url('/img/loading/loading.gif')  no-repeat center center"`

Answer (score 60):

You would need to use Javascript for this. You can set the style of the `background-image` for the body like so.

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://localhost/background.png)';
```

Just make sure you replace the URL with the **actual** URL.

Comment: hi THANKS, but i do not get any changes from the code below.
<script type="text/javascript">
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.style.backgroundImage = 'http://localhost/ABC/images/backgrounds/header-top1.jpg';
</script>

Comment: You need to either put it at the the end of the body tag or called it when the document loads.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Just one question; why not use `document.body` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]`?

Comment: IIRC `document.body` is DOM Level 0 and widely supported historically. [According to `devdocs.io`](http://devdocs.io/dom/document/body) it's not preferred as Firefox may not treat it correctly if the document MIME type is not set to `text/html` or `application/xhtml+xml`.

Answer (score 10):

Just set an onload function on the body:

```
<body onload="init()">
```

Then do something like this in javascript:

```
function init() {
  var someimage = 'changableBackgroudImage';
  document.body.style.background = 'url(img/'+someimage+'.png) no-repeat center center'
}
```

You can change the 'someimage' variable to whatever you want depending on some conditions, such as the time of day or something, and that image will be set as the background image.

Answer (score 2):

If you're page has an [Open Graph](http://opengraphprotocol.org/) image, commonly used for social sharing, you can use it to set the background image at runtime with vanilla JavaScript like so:

```
<script>
  const meta = document.querySelector('[property="og:image"]');
  const body = document.querySelector("body");
  body.style.background = `url(${meta.content})`;
</script>
```

The above uses [`document.querySelector`](http://devdocs.io/dom/document/queryselector) and [Attribute Selectors](http://devdocs.io/css/attribute_selectors) to *assign* `meta` the first Open Graph image it selects. A similar task is performed to get the `body`. Finally, *string interpolation* is used to assign `body` the `background.style` the value of the path to the Open Graph image.

If you want the image to cover the entire *viewport* and stay fixed set [`background-size`](http://devdocs.io/css/background-size) like so:

```
body.style.background = `url(${meta.content}) center center no-repeat fixed`;
body.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
```

Using this approach you can set a low-quality background image placeholder using CSS and swap with a high-fidelity image later using an image `onload` event, thereby reducing *perceived latency*.