# javascript toggling background images

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have the following piece of JS which toggles the BG color from red to green and so on.

```
function blink() {
            var currentColor = 'red';
            setInterval(function () {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = currentColor;
                currentColor = currentColor === 'red' ? 'green' : 'red';
            }, 1000);
        };
```

Is there anyway to change the colours to images so it toggles between two images instead of two colours?

I have tried the following but without success:

```
function toggleBG() {
            var currentColor = "Images/tableBGRed.gif";
            setInterval(function () {
                var myDiv = document.getElementById("testDiv");
                myDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + currentColor + "')";
                currentColor = currentColor === "url('Images/tableBGRed.gif')" ? "url('Images/tableBG.gif')" : "url('Images/tableBGRed.gif')";
            }, 1000);
        };
```

Something wrong with the syntax?

Comment: have you set a height and width of your div as without content a div will be collapsed and will not be visible unless it has content or a height and width set.

Comment: This also might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867503/change-background-image-in-body Another thing you could try is just getting rid of the ?: syntax and using an actual if/else. I've never trusted that syntax myself.

Comment: Yes the div has content and with the toggleBG() function above the BG changes to red and just stays red, never actually changes to "url('Images/tableBG.gif')" it seems

Answer (score 2):

```
currentColor = currentColor === "url('Images/tableBGRed.gif')" ? "url('Images/tableBG.gif')" : "url('Images/tableBGRed.gif')";
```

will cause the string to become  something like `"url(url(' Images/cat.gif '))"`, which is not a valid value for  `myDiv.style.backgroundImage`,

since you've got `myDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + currentColor + "')";` in the previous line.

Updates:

You can use CSS3 to make it look like an animation (fading):

```
#testDiv{
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.1s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.1s ease;
transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems your code creates a backgroundimage as

```
url('url('Images/xxx.gif')')
```

Try

```
function toggleBG() {
    var currentColor = "url('Images/tableBGRed.gif')";
    setInterval(function () {
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("testDiv");
        myDiv.style.backgroundImage = currentColor;
        currentColor = currentColor === "url('Images/tableBGRed.gif')" ? "url('Images/tableBG.gif')" : "url('Images/tableBGRed.gif')";
    }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Yes that was it. Thank you. Is there a way to make the "animation" smoother? Like a fade in and out?

Comment: @sd_dracula My suggestion to you is to use jQuery or CSS3.

Comment: see http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/css-fundametals-css-3-transitions/ for information about CSS3 Transitions