# background gif on javascript to change css

Tags: javascript, html, css, gif

I'm trying to change the CSS of my website by the user clicking a div and when they do the website's background will turn into a gif, but I don't know how to do that on JavaScript!

here's my code

```
 function easterFun(){
     var changeBG = document.getElementById("body");
     changeEaster.setAttribute("style","background-image:url(eatser.gif)")
```

also my div wont do anything when it is clicked. it wont execute this code can someone tell me the problem pls??
    
    
    
    
    
    Welcome to the Holiday Spirit website!!!

```
<div  id="easter"onclick="easterFun" style = "cursor: pointer"()>Easter!</div>
<div id = "xmas" onclick ="xmasFun()">Christmas</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well you have an issue where your variables do not match `changeBG`  and `changeEaster`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867503/change-background-image-in-body

Comment: Is `eatser.gif` the correct filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `style.cssText` or `style.backgroundImage`

Example:

```
function easterFun(){
     var changeBG = document.getElementById("body");
     changeBG.style.cssText = "background-image: url(eatser.gif)";
}
```

Or:

```
function easterFun(){
     var changeBG = document.getElementById("body");
     changeBG.style.backgroundImage = "url(eatser.gif)";
}
```

Note:

`document.getElementById` capture only elements with ID (eg. `<div id="body">`)

For get "body element" use: `document.body` (or `document.getElementsTagName("body")[0]`), eg.:

```
function easterFun(){
     var changeBG = document.body;
     changeBG.style.backgroundImage = "url(eatser.gif)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
changeEaster.style.backgroundImage = "url(eatser.gif)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. You need to change `getElementById` to `getElementsByTagName` and match your variables:

```
function easterFun(){
     document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("style","background-image:url(eatser.gif)");
}
```

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array of objects, which is why after the function call, we access `[0]`.

In the above, I have also removed the variable declaration for brevity.