# Changing Background Image using JS function while using FLASK

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to change the background image using javascript. I'm using FLASK and Jinga templating for making my website. I am having an confusion with the following code.

I have tried using different inverted commas, but it didn't work. In CSS, it's working fine, but in JS it isn't. Thanks in advance :)

```
    document.body.style.backgroundImage=  "url(\"{{url_for('static', filename ='sacred5.jpg' )\")}}";
```

Comment: Needs to be done on `load` event - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10867973/546000

Answer (score 0):

You can either specify the `background-image` using inline CSS or make the change using `js` once the page has loaded:

Inline version:

In `template.html`:

```
<html>
  <body style='background-image:url({url})'>
     ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Then, in `app.py`:

```
@app.route('/your_route', methods=['GET'])
def your_route():
   return flask.render_template('template.html', url='/static/sacred5.jpg')
```

Using `jQuery`, in your `homepage.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').css('background-image', '/static/sacred5.jpg');
});
```