# How can I change the background image of an HTML id, via a radio button, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button, background-image

I'm working on/struggling with some Javascript for a project. Currently I have only an index.html, which contains five sections, each with their own id, and each with a different background-image allocated to these sections.

I have a button in the footer, which when clicked, should change each of these section background-images to a different image.

The current background-image for #landingImage is DSC3719.jpg and I would want it to change to DSC7317.jpg, when I click the radio button.

Having watched *hours* of tutorial videos, I'm no further forward on how I should bring this idea together. The most recent tutorial I've watched has suggested using an if/else, with an alternative class for the background-image to be switched to. With this method in mind, I would have to use multiple classes, as the alternative image is different for each section. Is this correct?

I'm not looking for the code to be written for me, but a process on how to approach this issue.

I'd be grateful for any guidance!

Cheers.

```css
#landingImage{
  background-image: url(../img/DSC3719.jpg);
  min-width:100%;
  min-height: 700px;
  position:relative;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
 <div>
     <input class="switch" type="checkbox" value="" id="footerBtn">
     <label class="switch-btn" for="footerBtn"></label>
 </div>
```

Comment: Are you want custom radio button using javascript and css. this might helps https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/radio-button/how-to/customize-radiobutton-appearance/

Comment: @RayeesAC _"I'm ... looking for ... a process on how to approach this issue."_ - How does it help OP to use a library for this?

Comment: @Andreas He actually didn't understand the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *...contains five sections, each with their own id, and each with a different background-image allocated to these sections.*
> *I have a button in the footer, which when clicked, should change each of these section background-images to a different image.*

How about toggling classes?

Here is how to change multiple images

In this SPECIFIC case, the images are all defined in the CSS. It is possible to use data-attributes, but in this case, I would prefer to keep all the image URLs in one place

Note I destruct the querySelectorAll since not all newer browsers support the forEach on an html collection

```js
document.getElementById("footerBtn").addEventListener("click",function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".coverImage")]
    .forEach(img => img.classList.toggle("checked",this.checked))
})
```

```css
.coverImage {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 700px;
  position: relative;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#landingImage {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/700?text=landing1.jpg);
}
#landingImage.checked {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/700?text=landing2.jpg);
}

#otherImage {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/700?text=other1.jpg);
}
#otherImage.checked {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/700?text=other2.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="switch" type="checkbox" value="" id="footerBtn">
  <label class="switch-btn" for="footerBtn"></label>
</div>

<div id="landingImage" class="coverImage"></div>
<div id="otherImage" class="coverImage"></div>
```

Comment: `id` has a higher specificity than class. You could use `#landingImage.checked`

Comment: Incredible. Sincerely thank you all for this breakdown. I've been really struggling with Javascript, and this was the first of many issues I need to tackle.

Comment: you don't need to destructure the `querySelectorAll` call

Comment: @pilchard I do for some older browsers like EDGE<17

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with CSS using the `:checked` pseudo class and a sibling combinator.

```css
#landingImage{
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080");
  min-width:100%;
  min-height: 700px;
  position:relative;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.switch:checked ~ #landingImage {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF");
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input class="switch" type="checkbox" value="" id="footerBtn">
    <label class="switch-btn" for="footerBtn"></label>
    
    <div id="landingImage"></div>
 </div>
```

As commented, the CSS solution may become cumbersome with multiple images to change.

To implement this in javascript you can store the intended alternate image src in a `data` attribute in the HTML and then iterate over the relevant elements on checkbox change.

> HTML5 is designed with extensibility in mind for data that should be associated with a particular element but need not have any defined meaning. data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as non-standard attributes, extra properties on DOM, or Node.setUserData().

[Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

```js
function toggleImages() {
  // get all elements with class 'alt-image'
  const altImages = document.querySelectorAll('.alt-image');
  // iterate over the resulting NodeList
  altImages.forEach(image => {
    // check if the image has been switched
    if (!image.classList.contains('alt-active')) {
      // if not, get the alt-src from the data attribute
      const altsrc = image.getAttribute('data-alt-src');
      // set the alt url on the element
      image.style.backgroundImage = `url("${altsrc}")`;
      // add a class indicating it has been toggled
      image.classList.add('alt-active');
    } else {
      // if so, set the url to '' (the src specified in the CSS will be used)
      image.style.backgroundImage = '';
      // remove the active class
      image.classList.remove('alt-active');
    }
  });
}

// query the document for the toggle switch
const toggle = document.querySelector('.switch');

// add onchange listener to the toggle
toggle.addEventListener('change', toggleImages, false);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.alt-image {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 20vw;
  padding: 16px;
  position:relative;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#landing1{
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150/000F0F");
}
 #landing2{
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150/FFFF00");
}
#landing3{
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF00F8");
}
#landing4{
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150/808080");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div id="landing1" class="alt-image" data-alt-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF"></div>
<div id="landing2" class="alt-image" data-alt-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000"></div>
<div id="landing3" class="alt-image" data-alt-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FFFF00"></div>
<div id="landing4" class="alt-image" data-alt-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <input class="switch" type="checkbox" value="" id="footerBtn">
    <label class="switch-btn" for="footerBtn"></label>
 </div>
```

Comment: And changing the image?

Comment: And if he need to change many section image? OP: _should change each of these section background-images_

Comment: I would personally prefer to not have data-attributes to keep the image URLs in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in my example i add `onChange` for use my function everytime checkbox is checked, and simple change background.

```js
function ChangeBG(checkbox){
  const landingImage = document.getElementById('landingImage');
  if(checkbox.checked){
    landingImage.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://via.placeholder.com/150')";
  }else{
    landingImage.style.backgroundImage = "url('../img/DSC3719.jpg')";
  }
}
```

```css
#landingImage{
  background-image: url(../img/DSC3719.jpg);
  min-width:100%;
  min-height: 700px;
  position:relative;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <input class="switch" type="checkbox" value="" id="footerBtn" onChange="ChangeBG(this);">
     <label class="switch-btn" for="footerBtn"></label>
 </div>
 
 
 <div id="landingImage"></div>
```

Comment: You are welcome ;) when you can acept my answer please.

Comment: This would have to repeat code for each of the 5 images . Also not recommended to have inline event handlers

Comment: Why repeat the code for each? just create the variable and add it in the `IF`

Comment: _Also not recommended to have inline event handlers_  why?

Comment: You will have background image in the CSS AND in the JavaScript AND have to maintain both.

Comment: Ah yes @mplungjan, re: the **onChange**, the tutorial did mention inline event handling. So it'd be the same with onClick then.

Comment: `document.getElementById("footerBtn").addEventListener("click",function() {})` is the preferred method. You can discuss click or change - I prefer click since older browsers did not react to the change event until blur

Answer (score 0):

The missing step could be:

1. You need to bind an event handler to the checkbox. Very easy is the onclick event: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_display_checkbox_text.asp
2. You need to change the background image: [change background image in body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867503/change-background-image-in-body) (The first answer uses jQuery, scroll down for vanilla JS)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you @PotatoesFall for the link! I suppose what I didn't include in my initial question was the idea of using eventHandlers as opposed to onclick, which was also suggested by another user. By all means, very grateful for your input!