# Pascal To C Translation

Tags: c, winapi, graphics, gdi, freepascal

I have a program that takes a shot of the screen in pascal:

```
uses Graphics, 
     LCLIntf, 
     LCLType;

var  
     Screen:   TBitmap;
     ScreenDC: HDC;
begin
     Screen    := TBitmap.Create;
     ScreenDC  := GetDC(0);
     Screen.LoadFromDevice(ScreenDC);
     ReleaseDC(0, ScreenDC);
     Screen.SaveToFile("Screen.bmp");
end.
```

My question rests on the `LoadFromDevice()`, and `SaveToFile()` functions. What function(s), (if any), could be used to implement these in the C programming language. Trying to keep away from third party libraries as close a possible. (WinAPI)

Comment: WinAPI **is** a third party library. Anyway googling "winapi screenshot" should give you plenty of references. And [the first one](http://wiki.freepascal.org/LCL_Internals) is from freepascal wiki.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997175/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-and-save-it-as-jpeg-on-windows

Comment: Nothing. There is no such thing as a "screen" in C. You will need some platform-specific functionality. In you case, the winapi sounds like a good candidate.

Comment: Yep, this is not translating Pascal to C, it's translating from using one set of APIs to using another set.  You could have essentially the same work to do going between two different Pascal platforms.

Comment: What do you mean by "Third-party" API? What would be an example of a "first-party API" by your working definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look At this

```
HDC hDC = GetDC(g_hWnd); 
LPRECT rect = (LPRECT)malloc(sizeof(RECT)); 
GetWindowRect(g_hWnd,rect); 
int h = rect->right - rect->left;
int w = rect->bottom - rect->top; 
LPRECT rect = (LPRECT)malloc(sizeof(RECT)); 

GetWindowRect(g_hWnd,rect); 
HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC,w,h); 
PBITMAPINFO pbmi;
pbmi = CreateBitmapInfoStruct(g_hWnd,hBmp); 

CreateBMPFile(g_hWnd, TEXT("c:\\TEMPO\\TestG2.bmp"), pbmi, hBmp, hDC) ;
ReleaseDC(g_hWnd,hDC); 
DeleteObject(hBmp); 
DeleteObject(pbmi); 

if (rect != nullptr)
    free(rect);
```

Comment: Why are you malloc'ing the `RECT`? Why not use stack-allocation?