# How to release an object created from GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP?

Tags: c, winapi, bitmap, gdi+

I'm writing a C application and in my code I'm calling the constructor `GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP`.

I know the constructor should not be called from C, but I used a "hack" from here "[How can I take a screenshot and save it as JPEG on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997175/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-and-save-it-as-jpeg-on-windows/1034609#1034609)"

I'm not sure how to release resources that were allocated during the call to `GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP`.

I tried finding help in the documentation but found nothing.

```
ULONG *pBitmap = NULL;
lGdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP = (pGdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP)GetProcAddress(hModuleThread, "GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP");
lGdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP(hBmp, NULL, &pBitmap);
```

How to I release `pBitmap`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: C does not have constructors.  no problem code is posted, suggest closing this question

Comment: Of course C does not have constructors, but a constructor is simply a normal function. And by using some "hacks" (as described above) I can call the Bitmap constructor from C and create a valid Bitmap object.

Comment: are you looking for `GdipDisposeImage()`

Comment: Sounds so ! Will a call to GdipDisposeImage be enough in order to completely release all the resources allocated at GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP ? P.S Please post an answer so I can mark your response as correct.

Comment: @RemyLebeau has you covered.  `hBmp` will need `DeleteObject()` as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is not a "hack".  Although GDI+ is primarily designed to be used in C++, it does expose a [flat API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533969.aspx) for use in C.  Your code is using that API.  `GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP()` is not a constructor, it is a flat C function that is called by the [`Bitmap.Bitmap(HBITMAP, HPALETTE)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536314.aspx) constructor.

That being said, `GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP()` returns a pointer to a `GpBitmap` object (which is wrapped by the [`Bitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534420.aspx) class in C++).  `GdipDisposeImage()` is the correct way to release that object (which is called by the [`Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534462.aspx) destructor in C++).

```
struct GpImage {};
struct GpBitmap {};
typedef GpStatus (WINGDIPAPI *pGdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP)(HBITMAP, HPALETTE hpal, GpBitmap**);
typedef GpStatus (WINGDIPAPI *GdipDisposeImage)(GpImage *image);
```

```
GpBitmap *pBitmap = NULL;
lGdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP = (pGdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP) GetProcAddress(hModuleThread, "GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP");
lGdipDisposeImage = (pGdipDisposeImage) GetProcAddress(hModuleThread, "GdipDisposeImage");
//...
lGdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP(hBmp, NULL, &pBitmap);
//...
lGdipDisposeImage((GpImage*)pBitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks Remy for your contribution. Any idea why `GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP` takes so much memory? for bitmap with a resolution of 2560 x 1440, it takes around 14448 MB of RAM.